# Add AndEngine library as jar

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, andengine, libraries

I have tried to add AndEngine in several ways but it didn't work. The tutorials I followed were for GLES2 and I did exactly what they asked me to do.

1. I updated Eclipse
2. I made Java Compilance is 1.6
3. I have checked the needed things in Order and Export

It didn't work when i added the Library AndEngine to my dummy game.So i put the jar of this library in my Lib folder added it to my libraries and checked it in Order and Export.

[image: Project Properties]

This solution worked but i can only use the codes for the AndEngine like Scene/camera.
I added the AndEngine library to AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension in same way i did for my project (As jar) and i imported AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension to my project as jar.
I can use the codes related to AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension but when i launch the app on any Real/virtual device it crashes.It didn't crash when i removed the codes related to AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.

What I need:
I need a solution to be able to add AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension as Jar and be able to Run it without the error shown below (i tried running it on Real and virtual devices)

OR

I need to know how can I add AndEngine in this way

[image]

Without getting this error

[image]

The error I get when I import AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension as Jar is

```
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083): MainActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 33368')
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreateScene(MainActivity.java:71)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:169)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreateResources(MainActivity.java:53)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension: findLibrary returned null
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
05-14 21:34:27.388: E/AndEngine(14083):     ... 8 more
```

**Edit**

Jar Libraries are put in the projects as shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your AndEngine jar into the physical directory for your workspace containing your project. That will keep Eclipse from incorrectly using symbolic linking or the incorrect absolute path (which is what tends to happen).

Comment: i have already added it to the libs folder of my project , imported it then i checked it in the Order and export.

Comment: Don't do all of that, just copy AndEngine.jar or whatever it may be into your workspace (for example if it is C:/Users/You/YourWorkspace then put it in that directory). And if you try to copy it directly through eclipse (right clicking on your folder and clicking paste or dragging it into the folder) it will try to create an incorrect reference link.

Comment: AndEngine worked when i put it as Jar but AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension  the other jar that adds more options didn't work (i can use all the AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension codes but when i run it its dosen't work)

Comment: I can look into it some more, but if you are sure that your libraries are in the same directory as your workspace, you shouldn't have an issue adding them as a jar or linking them directly (like you are trying to do in the second part). The second part fails (where you click add library) because the library isn't in the same directory as your workspace.

Comment: I found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681383/add-andengine-library