# Add AndEngine Library

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I got AndEngine from github and did as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And i got AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension and did:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that i added the libraries to my App

[image]

[image]

I then imported

[image]

[image]

But then when i press OK and open the properties of my app i get this

[image]

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem , I just pressed Apply after importing the libraries then pressed OK. I honestly don't know why pressing Apply then OK works but pressing OK directly doesn't work.

Comment: `I just pressed Accept after importing the libraries then pressed OK` where is this **Accept**?

Comment: @Muhammad Babar No it's Apply not accept, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't import the andengine project. just use andengine jar-file as library and it will work well. you can find the jar-files in the bin-folder of the project. and when i'm not wrong, then this error comes, when you don't copy the files of andengine into your work space, while you imported the andengine project's

Comment: when i added AndEngine as Jar it worked perfectly but i have another library which is AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension . when i added AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension as Jar and used some of it's codes it didn't work (I get no errors when i use the codes of this library but it will crash when the project starts). The library i should import for AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension  is AndEngine.

Comment: what crash report do you get?